# How do you run multiple lines of CMD code in VB.net?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, cmd

I'm trying to run a couple of lines of code in vb.net which I can get each individual part to work but not together.

The first part starts the `cmd.exe` process then pushes you to the mysql bin directory, I'm guessing I need to be able to force it to press enter or something like that but I'm struggling to do so. Then I want it to run through the second part which just basically asks you to log in to the database (which requires that previous directory and to check a specific database).
I'd rather not have to import multiple batch files and have it embedded into the exe file directly.

Any suggestions? The code I've been working is below.

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k pushd C:\mysql\bin" & " mysql -u root -p checktable Database1")
```

Answer (score 1):

PushD is forinteractive use. Programmers will never use it or CD. We use full paths so programs do exactly what we tell them too.

& joins commands on a line.

So IF YOU HAD two legitimite commands

```
 dir c:\ & type %windir%\win.ini
```

But as you don't

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k C:\mysql\bin\mysql -u root -p checktable Database1"
```